# App crashes everytime on start without any errors

Tags: android

I am trying to implement  [this](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Applying-Custom-TTF-Fonts-in-an-Android-Application-Using-Typeface)  code to my application and use my fonts in the `assets/fonts`.I didn‘t get any exception in the logcat but.Everytime launch it.It collapse.What am i doing wrong

Here is mycode

```
public class appp  extends Application {
      private Typeface normalFont;
        private Typeface boldFont;



        // -- Fonts -- //
        public void setTypeface(TextView textView) {
            if(textView != null) {
                if(textView.getTypeface() != null && textView.getTypeface().isBold()) {
                    textView.setTypeface(getBoldFont());
                } else {
                    textView.setTypeface(getNormalFont());
                }
            }
        }

        private Typeface getNormalFont() {
            if(normalFont == null) {
                normalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/SERSAL.ttf");
            }
            return this.normalFont;
        }

        private Typeface getBoldFont() {
            if(boldFont == null) {
                boldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Cheboyga.ttf");
            }
            return this.boldFont;
        }

}
```

and this is  Main Class

```
appp  application = (appp) getApplication();
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
        application.setTypeface(myTextView);
```

Comment: You are using custom Application so have delcared this **android:name="your packagename.appp"** in your manifest??

Comment: Withouy any extra classes you can simply use custom font like this
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SERSAL.ttf");
  myTextView .setTypeface(tf);

Comment: can you see my answer?

Comment: That sample code you link to is possibly the worst use of the `Application` class I've ever seen.

Comment: Thank you guys @kalyan I cant get your response as an answer .Its just comment.Plase send an answer so ı can tick it

Comment: @user2583511 ok..posted my comment as answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using custom Application so you have delcare this

`android:name="your packagename.appp"` in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can set type face  like this:

```
 Typeface font;
 font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "xxx.ttf"); 
 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
 myTextView.setTypeface(font);
```

Can you check this should work,

Answer (score 0):

Each application has its own manifest file with the unique package name.

You should have it like for each app as unique.

Like for app1, you may have -

```
package="com.package.app1"
```

To access the package name use -

```
public String getAppName()
{
    final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();


    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");

    return applicationName;
}
```

Same applies for application tags..

```
<application android:name="com.package.app1.app"> ... </application>
```